# How does Ractive's proxy-load work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ractivejs

I want to know when a DOM element generated by Ractive is ready. In my case, I want to use jquery to attach an autocomplete function onto the element. Ideally it would go something like this:

Template:

```
{{#list}}
<input type="text" proxy-load="attach-typeahead">
{{/list}}
```

Javascript:

```
ractive.on("attach-typeahead", function(event){
    $(event.node).typeahead(...);
})
```

But the event never fires even though I remeber seeing proxy-load mentioned somewhere in the documentation. What's the proper way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codler's answer is spot on - transitions can be used to attach behaviour to nodes (and detach it, with `outro`).

As of the latest (0.3.8) version, there's another method, which behaves similarly but is slightly more streamlined for this purpose: **decorators**.

The documentation hasn't been written yet (my bad), but you can see a [typeahead decorator here](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/vFL4n/). A decorator is simply a function that gets called as soon as a node is added to the DOM, and which returns an object with a `teardown()` method that gets called as soon as the node is removed from the DOM.

You can make a decorator globally available like so:

```
Ractive.decorators.foo = function ( node ) {
  // do some setup work with the node here...

  return {
    teardown: function () {
      // do any necessary cleanup here
    }
  };
};
```

Or you can specify per-instance decorators, as in the fiddle.

[Another decorator example here](http://ractivejs.github.io/Ractive-decorators-sortable/), this time a sortable list.

Comment: Hey Rich I looked at your fiddle and it works great except that I can't get the value of the input. For example, the template is now <input ... value="{{country}}"> and then I type "a" into the box and select the suggested "Avon". Now when I do ractive.get("country"), it only gives me "a" back instead of "Avon".

Comment: See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/vFL4n/3/) - there's some undocumented implementation details in there (the `node._ractive` stuff) which I need to write up, but you get the gist - we're responding to the typeahead plugin's custom events to update the model.

Comment: Thanks Rich! I see what's happening now.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy-events are mentioned [here](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/wiki/Ractive.eventDefinitions) in the documentation of ractive. Your example doesn't work because the input element does not have a native load event.

All the ractive functions have a complete function callback that fires when the rendering has completed. Maybe you can use that.

Comment: Are you talking about transition functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `intro` attribute. It is a transition in ractive. When the DOM are created, intro will be called.
You can find more info here https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/wiki/Transitions